# Node disjoint paths with node splitting

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I have a not so large network/graph that contains roughly 4000 edges and 1200 different nodes. Each edge has a weight (or cost) and a type (let's say either red or green). Going from one type of edge to another should add an additional cost to the total cost of the desired path. So staying in the same type of edges will not add any cost, but switching between edge types will.

**Problem:**
The problem I would like to solve is to find/calculate two redundant paths between two nodes that in total have the minimum cost. I.e. the paths can't have any overlapping nodes.

**My attempt at a solution, so far:**

In order to add additional costs between edge types, this was solved with some help from another SO user, by duplicating all nodes into `green` and `red` nodes, and then creating `green` and `red` edges between the same type of nodes (see figure). The idea was then to add the additional cost to a new edge between nodes that had both `green` and `red` edges going through them.

[image]

Now, in order to find two node disjoint paths with minimum cost I have implemented Suurballes node disjoint algorithm (http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Disjoint_Path_Finding). However, the issue with this come when incorporating the additional edge-switching cost. If the first path goes through one node that has both `green` and `red` connections, this node is split up into two nodes (`green` and `red`). This means that if the path doesn't go through the split edge, i.e. the intersection, it has only visited e.g. the `green` node. Hence, the `red` node has not been visited, and is still up for grabs for the second path. This basically makes the node disjoint path not true, since it is still possible to visit the other one of the split nodes.

Basically, with what I have done so far I am able to either add the additional cost by splitting the nodes as seen in the figure, or find node disjoint paths with the original graph with no node-splitting using Suurballes node disjoint path algorithm. But I haven't been able to merge these two.

Comment: Please specify the "calculate the TWO shortests node disjoint paths in some network" problem more precisely.  I don't know exactly what that means.  What are the inputs to the algorithm, and what is the desired output?  I asked for a similar clarification on the last question you asked here and never got one, and it led to confusion (where one person answered with an algorithm that I suspect solved a different problem than the one you actually wanted solved), so it is important to be precise in the question about the exact problem you want an algorithm for.

Comment: I have added a bit more detail.

Comment: "Surballe's algorithm" is not a specification of a problem statement; it is a way to solve a problem, not a description of the problem to be solved.   Please state the problem in a clean way, not the method for solving it.  The first step in solving any problem is being able to clearly articulate the problem to be solved and all requirements that a solution must satisfy (or what evaluation metrics you will use for evaluating candidate solutions).

Comment: The structure of the question makes it hard for me to understand the problem.  The problem statement is listed as "I want to solve problem X" followed by a long narrative of some additional requirements interweaved with your current thoughts about how you might deal with those additional requirements.  I encourage you to provide a self-contained, standalone specification of the problem, separated from your thoughts on how you might solve it.

Comment: You say you want node disjoint paths, but Suurballe's algorithm produces edge disjoint paths, not node disjoint paths.  Yet another reason why I hope you can state the problem more precisely.

Comment: I have revised it once again. However, Suurballes algorithm (the one I use in this case) can be extended to find node disjoint paths. If I'm not mistaken, this was actually the original algorithm proposed by Suurballe, while the extended one (Suurballe/Tarjan) was for edge disjoint paths. Also, what I was trying to do (although the quesion/problem perhaps were a bit vague) was showing what I have done so far. Usually that is what people are asking for in here, so that you just don't ask a question, and let other people do the entire work. But I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: What does "redundant paths" mean?  Please specify whether it is a directed or undirected graph.

Comment: When you say "can't have any overlapping nodes", do you mean "except for the start and end nodes"?

Comment: Redundant just mean, that they can't overlap at all. So in the case of one path being dead (not being able to be used), the other path should be an alternative route to and from the same two nodes. It is a directed graph. And yes, the start and end nodes can overlap.

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it contains all relevant information and reads well for someone who encounters the web page for the first time.  We don't want people to have to dig through the comments to understand your question.  Of course, any two such paths will overlap at the start and end, so "can't overlap at all" is not achievable, as I was hinting by my question.